# How to Extract Credentials from this Function?

Tags: javascript, methods, fs

I am trying to extract the "parse" variable from this chunk of code. My goal is to get it to be used as a global variable outside of the function. Right now I am assigning it to credentials.
How do I return var credentials with the updated parse information?
I am using the fs module in node.js to read my credentials file.

Right now this code is returning "undefined" when I call it via readcredentials();

```
function readCredentials() {
  var credentials = 2
  fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    var parse = JSON.parse(content);
    parse = credentials;
  });
  return credentials;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because the callback is async. i.e, by the time callback processes the data, it moves down and returns the current value of `credentials` which is `2`. Execution has to wait to have the value of credentials ready. 
More clearer way of handling this would be to use promise.

```
const fs = require("fs");

function readCredentials() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
      if (err) return reject('Error loading client secret file:', err);
      return resolve(JSON.parse(content));
    });
  });
}

readCredentials()
  .then(res=>{
    console.log("Res:", res)
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log("Error:", err);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
So i'm seeing the credentials in the console. How would I push that res variable into a global variable? @Kullya

Comment: let res = readCredentials()
  .then(res=>{
    return res;
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.log("Error:", err);
  })